# How do I reduce multiple nested if statements in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with a code snippet that iterates over an object list and filters out objects to perform a specific task. The `for` loop consists of multiple nested `if` statements (and I'll probably add more in the future).

Here's my code:

```
for obj in objects:
  if 'x' not in obj.name:
    if 'y' not in obj.name:
      if 'z' not in obj.name:
        if obj.length > 0:
          if obj.is_directory == True:
            
            # Do Something
```

Is there a neat or efficient workaround for this snippet?

Please Advise

Comment: common technique is inversing the condition and using early returns/break/continue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also write:

```
for obj in objects:
   if not any(c in obj.name for c in 'xyz') and obj.length > 0 and obj.is_directory:
      # Do something
```

In case `x`, `y` and `z` are not single characters the solution remains the same. A string in Python is a sequence of characters, so you can substitute the `'xyz'` string with the sequence (list) of words. You can put any iterable in there as well.

```
for obj in objects:
   if not any(w in obj.name for w in [word1, word2, word3]) and obj.length > 0 and obj.is_directory:
      # Do something
```

Comment: The x, y, z in my actual case are words like `word1`, `word_2`, `_word3` how do I use that in your answer?

Comment: @Luke I edited my answer with a short explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can put them all into one if statement with `and` between each condition:

```
for obj in objects:
    if ('x' no in obj.name) and ('y' not in obj.name) and ('z' not in obj.name)
    and (obj.length > 0) and (obj.is_directory):
        #Do Something
```

Note that it is not necessary to check if `obj.is_directory == True`, and it will evaluate to true itself if it is true.